# Live system backup or cloning?

Tags: backup, cloning, systemback

I -was- a great fan of Systemback & it saved me from some serious headaches in the past.

Its own dev abandoned it, and though there are forks of it I have yet to find any fork that is as dependable as the original was.

It's greatest ability IMO was to run on an active/running system to make an identical backup/clone of it which could be written to a USB stick or just used as a sort of rollback for when problems might occur.

My 'daily driver' PC remains at 18.04.5 and will likely be kept there with extended support because my exposures to 20.04+ have not impressed me very much.

There is a payware version of Systemback here:
.
https://www.alien-os.de/#Systemback-2
.
And yes - I actually paid the $10 or whatever it was - but the site is in German & its dev doesn't answer any support questions.

Any pointers for a utility to make full live system backups will be hugely appreciated - if anything else actually exists nowadays.

Thanks for reading.